# android AsyncTask does not dismiss Progressbar

Tags: android, android-asynctask

In my app i need to make call for AsyncTask in for loop like this

```
 protected void runSearch(String query) {


            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RESULT_COUNT; i += PAGE_SIZE) {
                try {
                    String s = SEARCH_ENDPOINT + "&q="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") + "&start=" + i;
                    // Toast.makeText(this, "qUERY>>  " + s + "",
                    //
                    // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("THISI SSS>>>>> ss" + s + "");

                    String se = SEARCH_ENDPOINT + "&q="
                            + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8") + "&start=" + i;


                    Get_Images get_images = new Get_Images();
                    get_images.execute(se);


                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO: handle error
                }
            }
        }
```

class Get_Images

```
public class Get_Images extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }


            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

                ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response

                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                 if (pDialog.isShowing())
                 {
                 pDialog.dismiss();
                 }
                if (ThumbImage != null) {

                    //Adpter fill
                }
            }

    }
```

The Problem is it does not dismiss Progress dialog. if it has created 3 dialog then does not dismiss any of them.

Pleas help
Thanks,

Comment: Is your onPostExecute() triggering ?

Comment: move your for loop inside async task class doInBackground() method and pass the query as parameter of async task class!

Comment: try replacing `ProgressDialog(getActivity())` to `ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext())`.

Comment: your logic is not correct. If you want to use async and block the user using Progress dialog then you should not show progress dialog on each async call. I would suggest you to use the library of universal image loader https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. Lazy loading for images is the best technique.

Comment: you can do as @StackOverflowUser stated, or simply show the progress before the for loop and dismiss it after for loop ends. that looks more sense ...?

Comment: @Njeebullah I have used Universal Image Loader in Adpter

Comment: @Android then why are you using Async Class. Universal Image Loader does that for you. Just use for loop and pass the url of your image and imageview to the displayImage or loadImage methods and the library will do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think by calling `AsyncTask` in `for` loop, it might start another task while the previous one still in `doInbackground()` that will result in multiple progress running because of this:

`pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());`

You will have a reference on the last started progress, so **calling 
dismiss will only hide last one, while the other X progress(es) will remain active**.

So, either:

1. Start the progress one time, before starting the `for loop`
   and stop it at `onPostExecute()` of last asyncTask

Or

2. Move the for loop inside `doInBackground()` as @StackOverflowUser stated